# Adding simple array to JSON payload in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: arrays, json, botframework, payload

I have a simple problem where I am not able to **insert an array in json payload to call graph api** to update user profile while using **Bot Framework Composer**.

Example:

**Step1.** I created a property Conversation.UpdatedSkills which holds following value

```
["SharePoint","Dotnet","Analytics"]
```

Now I want to build JSON object for MS Graph service and working sample payload looks like this.

```
{
   "skills":["SharePoint","Dotnet","Analytics"]
}
```

**Step2.** Now to build this JSON dynamically, I need pass body as JSON Object in Send an HTTP Request activity and I have folllowing code to generate payload.

```
{
    "skills":"${conversation.UpdatedSkills}"
}
```

The output from Step2 looks something like this.

```
{

    “skills”: “[\r\n “SharePoint”,\r\n “Dotnet”,\r\n “Analytics”\r\n]”

}
```

***DESIRED JSON WAS THIS:***

```
 {
       "skills":["SharePoint","Dotnet","Analytics"]
 }
```

My question is, How do I pass my array from step 1 such a way so that it creates json object that works in service. The object created using step 2 is not the right object that service takes.

Any idea?

I tried different string manipulations but I think this is basic and there has to be something.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the string interpolation `${ }`, but use an expression (`=`). For your example above, it should be:

```json
{
  "skills": "=conversation.UpdatedSkills"
}
```

Comment: Just had this issue and found your post. This should really be in the documentations...

Comment: it didn't work with me. i can actually see =conversation.updatedSkills printed as a string